# VBA Code: Vlookup Sheet1 to copy and paste on Sheet 2 if Sheet 1 contains specific text

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, vlookup

Picking your brains here.  Trying to do this for days.  VBA noob.

Two Sheets: Sourcesheet ("NB & COax PO Detail Test") & Outputsheet ("New build & Coax Test")

Source sheet is an organized list.  POs are in Col I and each POs value is broken down by month (J,F til dec).  Each row has is dedicated to a unique PO with the monthly forecast broken down by month.

Output Sheet has the POs listed in Rows and Monthly forecast in Columns. The idea is to vlookup the monthly forecast for each PO in source sheet, if the Col C (output sheet) is PO Materials or PO Labor then Vlookup, otherwise skip to next row.  Vlookup has to apply the monthly forecast to each month. After each Vlookup I am trying to copy and paste the value so that there isnt too much coding leading to Excel crash.  Also in the Source sheet the Col Index Num for the Output Sheet vlookup is listed above each month.

In a nutshell.

If(Or (Outputsheet.Col I ="PO Labor", Outputsheet.Col I ="PO Materials"), Vlookup(Outputsheet.ColE, SourceSheet.Range(Col I to Col AB:5000), SourceSheetR3,False), "") Copy and Paste next Column in the same row repeat until OutputSheet Col R.  Copy and paste.  Next row.

SourceSheet R3 is variable it changes so I want Vlookup to pick up the Column number from there as stated above each month of the Col.

(Output Sheet & Source Sheet Click the next image) http://imgur.com/SHANSLF&ydjQfb3#0
(Code) https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGwMx.jpg

Comment: It would really help if you posted an image instead of trying to explain the setup. It hurt my head reading that. You can upload on Imgur.com and link

Answer (score 0):

Finally finished this with the help of several genereous memebers of this community and Chandoo Community.  here is the final code that I put together and that actually works.

```
Sub MakeFormulas()
Dim SourceLastRow As Long
Dim OutputLastRow As Long
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
Dim X As Long
Dim Z As Long

'What are the names of our worksheets?
Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set outputSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")


'Determine last row of source
With sourceSheet
    SourceLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
With outputSheet

    'Determine last row in col C
  OutputLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
For y = 17 To 28 'Q to AB
  For X = 2 To OutputLastRow
  If InStr(1, .Range("C" & X), "PO Materials") + InStr(1, .Range("C" & X), "PO Labor") > 0 And Cells(2, y) = "Forecast" Then
  'Apply  formula
  .Cells(X, y).Value = _
  Evaluate("=VLOOKUP($E" & X & ",'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$L$" & SourceLastRow & ",Match(" & Cells(1, y).Address & ",'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$1:$AD$1,0),0)")
  End If
  Next
Next

End With
End Sub
```